# Align text in a GridViewTemplate field TextBox

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview

I need to align text to right in a `TextBox` which is in a `GridView` `TemplateField`

This is `TemplateField` HTML:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <div style="text-align: right;">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDeductAmount" runat="server" Text="" BorderWidth="1px"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle Width="80px" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This still aligned to left side. How to force text to align to right?

**NOTE :** `<ItemStyle Width="80px" HorizontalAlign="Right" />` aligns bound field text to right side properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This parameters do not change the input text box, but the table tags aligns.

To change how the input align the text add a class to it like.

```
.AlgRgh
{
  text-align:right;
  font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

and use `CssClass="AlgRgh"` on control

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDeductAmount" runat="server" Text="" BorderWidth="1px" CssClass="AlgRgh" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Or this:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Bank" SortExpression="BankID">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="BankIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BankID") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Hannington Mambo answers work perfect, the faster one is:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Bank" SortExpression="BankID">
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="BankIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BankID") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

When setting the values of the text box inside the `GridView` you can use this code in the `.cs`:

`((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[Index of the grid].FindControl("txtName")).Style.Add("text-align", "right");`